# RSpec check if method has been called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an `AccountsController` and a `destroy` action. I want to test if the account is being deleted and if the `subscription` is being canceled.

#### `AccountsController`

```rb
def destroy
  Current.account.subscription&.cancel_now!
  Current.account.destroy
end
```

#### RSpec

```rb
describe "#destroy" do
  let(:account) { create(:account) }
  
  it "deletes the account and cancels the subscription" do
    allow(account).to receive(:subscription)
    expect do
      delete accounts_path
    end.to change(Account, :count).by(-1)

    expect(account.subscription).to have_received(:cancel_now!)
  end
end
```

But the above test does not pass. It says,

```
(nil).cancel_now!
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Because the `account.subscription` returns `nil` it is showing this. How do I fix this test?

Comment: Did you mean `expect to have_received`? Not sure `allow to have_received` will produce this message.

Comment: And you get this message because `Current.account` in your controller is in no way related to `let(:account)` in your spec. You set up expectations on one thing, but use the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the account entity in the context of the controller to the account from the test

It could be

```
describe "#destroy" do
  let(:account) { create(:account) }
  
  it "deletes the account and cancels the subscription" do
    allow(Current).to receive(:account).and_return(account)
    # if the subscription does not exist in the context of the account  
    # then you should stub or create it...
    expect do
      delete accounts_path
    end.to change(Account, :count).by(-1)

    expect(account.subscription).to have_received(:cancel_now!)
  end
end
```

Regarding subscription

```
expect(account).to receive(:subscription).and_return(instance_double(Subscription))
# or
receive(:subscription).and_return(double('some subscription'))
# or
create(:subscription, account: account)
# or
account.subscription = create(:subscription)
# or other options ...
```